# how to limit WebviewScaffold to display limited content

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, youtube-api, flutter-layout

so I'm using a WebviewScaffold to show a Youtube channel.
I would prefer it to display only that youtube channel, I'm sort of new to these things and am not sure if there is an easier way to do it, maybe there is some sort of API to use, etc.

if there is no way to do it, can I pull the videos/playlists from youtube to display in-app?
obvs I would prefer the first option.

thanks!

Edit:  it should display just that channel without access to the rest of YouTube, no tool bar on the bottom etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *so I'm using a WebviewScaffold to show a Youtube channel. I would
>   prefer it to display only that youtube channel*

This is not very clear; could provide us with further explanation ? :)

EDIT : after talks in the comments here is what you can do :

```
new MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID",
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Widget webview"),
          ),
        ),
      },
    );
```

Just replace `CHANNEL_ID` by the ID from the channel you want to display.

An alternative solution would be to take advantage of [the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) by [making async call thanks to the http package](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data). That would allow you to display only what you want !

hope it helps

Comment: Ah okay, so first step is to add YouTube API. But how can I view only a specific channel?

Comment: so just adding the channel id was the main issue. caus ethe rest of youtube's UI is there,  i would like to take the second route.    how can i use youtubes API in a webview? i think its a dumb question, cause i dont know the first thing about API's...

Comment: it isn't a dumb question at all ! Basically it does not make sense to use a webview with an API, as APIs are made so that you can create your own view. Instead, you need to build your view and fetch data from YouTube thanks to the YouTube API. I found this video from a guy who builds a YouTube player with Flutter and the YouTube API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feQhHStBVLE hope it will help you :)